# Terminate gulp-watch task

Tags: gulp-watch

I want my gulp watch task to run only once, then stop watching.  Now, if I run 'gulp' from the command line, the watch tasks keeps the gulp task running.  I have to hit Ctrl-C to stop it.

Answer (score 2):

when you run gulp watch, it will keep watching for file changes until you cancel it with CTRL-C. I you do not want this, then you can make a separate gulp task to do your building.

You would have 2 tasks then: gulp watch and gulp build. As the build wouldn't run the watch task, it will stop when finished.

Please take a look at a GitHub project of mine where I do things like this: [skeletonSPA on GitHub](https://github.com/elgervb/skeletonSPA).
If you take a look at the `gulpfile.js`, you see that the `default` task will execute the `build` task.
The build task on its turn will execute `info`, `clean`, `styles`, `scripts`, `images`, `copy`, `todo`; leaving you with a full build and working frontend.

After running these tasks, it will stop and gives you focus to the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very basic example `GulpFile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    runSequence = require('gulp-sequence'),
    webpack = require('webpack-stream');

gulp.task('webpack', function() {
    return gulp.src('client/index.js')
        .pipe(webpack({
            output: {
                filename: 'dist/bundle.js'
            },
            devtool: 'source-map'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});

// other tasks

gulp.task('build', ['webpack', 'other tasks... ']);

gulp.task('watch', function(callback) {
    gulp.watch('./client/**/*.js', {}, ['webpack']);
    // more watches if required
});

gulp.task('default', function(callback) {
    runSequence('build', 'watch', callback);
});
```

`$ gulp build` > will just run `build` the once and then exit.

`$ gulp watch` > will start watching (`ctrl-c` to exit).

`$ gulp` > will execute `build` and after that's complete it will run `watch` (`ctrl-c` to exit).

Note: I'm using the `gulp-sequence` plug to ensure that when running `$ gulp` the build will complete before the watch begins.

Answer (score 0):

gulp.watch returns a FSWatcher object, which has a .close() method you can call to cancel the watch task:

```
var watchStream = gulp.watch(
    src, 
    {ignoreInitial: true},
    myGulpTask)

    .on("change", function (triggerFileName) {
        watchStream.close();
    });
```

`ignoreInitial = true` prevents the task from running when the watcher starts. `watchStream.close()` will cancel the watcher, but the task will run once. So all in all, you get one task run.

This is with Gulp 4.