# Gulp watch task does't exit on Ctrl C

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gulp, webpack

### Background

I am having this gulp watch task to handle sass compilation:

```js
import gulp from 'gulp';
import sass from 'gulp-sass';
import concat from 'gulp-concat';

gulp.task("compile-scss", () => {
  return gulp.src("assets/scss/**/*.scss")
    .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' })
    .on("error", sass.logError))
    .pipe(concat("style.css"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/css"));
});

gulp.task("watch-scss", ['compile-scss'], () => {
  gulp.watch("assets/scss/**/*.scss", ["compile-scss"]);
});
```

I am then running `gulp watch-scss` and the process correctly compiles my files and start watching for new changes.

### The problem

When I want watching to stop I am pressing `Ctrl+C` in the terminal and everything looks ok.

But then I make a change in the `.scss` file and expect it not be handled by the gulp task (should be already stopped). Anyway this change gets handled by the watch task as it seems still running.

[image: gulp process terminate attempt]

Looking at the terminal code you can see where I start `gulp watch-scss`, where I press `Ctrl+C` and where task continues executing on change.

### Environment details

**OS:** OS X 10.11 (El Capitan)
**gulp version:** 3.9.1
**node version:** 6.2.2
**babel-core version:** 6.11.4

### History

The problem could be related to Node itself. Going into that direction I tried several solutions like terminating the process from within gulp like so:

```js
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  process.exit();
});
```

It didn't help.
Read lot of info on that topic, but nothing helped. Here are two related questions, which didn't help either:

[Stop a gulp watch task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30044683/stop-a-gulp-watch-task)

[Terminate gulp-watch task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930288/terminate-gulp-watch-task)

I can provide more details if needed.

Comment: what happens when you suspend the process? can you `Ctrl+Z` and then kill the stopped process by looking up its process id with `ps T`?

Comment: Does it exit if you press `Ctrl-c` twice?

Comment: also, try this with node's LTS version (4.4.0)

Comment: @MarcoS doing `Ctrl-C` twice didn't help.
@EliranMalka I tried doing `Ctrl+Z` and then successfully killed the process. The problem is that this is not a long term solution. I would like to make `Ctrl+C` or `Ctrl+Z` working.

**Something interesting:**
When I do `Ctrl+Z` I get this error
`throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read EIO
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1007:11)
    at TTY.onread (net.js:563:26)
`

Answer (score -1):

Close the terminal and the session will be terminated. Run gulp again and try if CTRL + C works.